# How to disable GPS using HTML5/phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, html, cordova

I need to do a function which disable/enable GPS from iphone and android

Comment: I have tried but not found...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't disable or enable it on the phone. That is controlled by the phone's settings and isn't accessible by PhoneGap API or HTML5.

By default, on iPhone, location services are disabled for an app until you try to access them                                                                     using:

```js
window.navigator.geolocation
```

Once you've done that, the user will be prompted to give that app permission to use location services. If they approve, it's on.

On Android, the permissions are set when installing the app. If they approve permissions, it's on.